# PowerShell Copy Files to AWS Bucket with Object Lock

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I want to copy CSV files generated by an SSIS package from an AWS EC2 server to an S3 bucket. Each time I try I get an error around the content-MD5 HTTP error because we have object lock enabled on the bucket.

```
Write-S3Object : Content-MD5 HTTP header is required for Put Object requests with Object Lock parameters
```

I would assume there is a PowerShell command I can add or I am missing something but after furious googling I cannot find a resolution.  Any help or an alternative option would be appreciated.

I am now testing using the AWS CLI process instead of PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do want to continue to use the `Write-S3Object` PowerShell command the missing magic flag is:

`-CalculateContentMD5Header 1`

So the final command will be

```
Write-S3Object -Region $region -BucketName $bucketName -File $fileToBackup -Key $destinationFileName -CalculateContentMD5Header 1
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-S3Object.html

Comment: mate, thank you for posting on an old thread this one has been frustrating for a while!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, reading and frustration I found the AWS CLI was able to do exactly what I needed.  I am unsure if this is an issue with my PowerShell knowledge or a missing feature (I lean toward my knowledge).

I created a bat file that used the CLI to move the files into the S3 bucket, I then called this bat file from within an SSIS execute task process.
Dropped the one line code below just in case it may help others.

aws s3 mv C:\path\to\files\ s3://your.s3.bucket.name/ --recursive